# Using OR on a pattern in Android

Tags: java, android, string, validation

I'm trying to validate an EditText field with a method that will check to see if the text in the EditText box is `"Monday"` OR `"Tuesday"` OR `"Wednesday"` etc, I have used a similar method to validate an ID code however the || operator doesn't work in this situation so i'm not sure how to go about doing it.

```
    private boolean isValidCode(String code) {
    String Code_Pattern = "[A-Z]" + "[A-Z]" + "[0-9]" + "[0-9]" + "[0-9]" + "[0-9]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Code_Pattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(code);
    return matcher.matches();
}
private boolean isValidDayOfWeek(String day) {
    String day_Pattern = "Monday" || "Tuesday"... ; //error here
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(day_Pattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(day);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

This is the button click method that validates the code correctly.

```
        Validate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String code = codeText.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidCode(code)) {
                codeText.setError("Invalid Code");
                validationError = true;
            }
            else {
                Validate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `String day_Pattern = "Monday||Tuesday"...`

Comment: Very quick fix, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having `Pattern Matching`, you can simply create an `Arraylist` of `String` type which will contains all days and when you have to validate it just check whether that arraylist contains that day or not.

```
final String code = codeText.getText().toString();
return arraylist.contains(code);
```